# Breaking Lines from Grid

Tags: java, loops, grid, awt, paint

The Grid looks like this.
http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/s320x320/532063_426018057411895_100000111130260_1879195_1266764275_n.jpg

I inserted the if statement in the loop for drawing the lines to make a line break.
However, the program functions as if the if statement is not there.
Is the if statement not enough?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Grid extends Canvas{

    Cell[][] maze;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int pathSize;
    double width, height;


    public Grid(int rows, int cols, int h, int w) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        maze = new Cell[rows][cols];
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(h,w));
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame y = new JFrame();
    y.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Grid f = new Grid(25,25,400,400);
    y.add(f, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    y.setSize(450,450);
    y.setVisible(true);
    y.setDefaultCloseOperation(y.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int k,j,z=0;
        width = getSize().width;
        height = getSize().height;

        double htOfRow = height / (rows);
        for (k = 0; k < rows; k++)
            for(j=0; j< rows+1; j++){
            if(j!=3){
            g.drawLine(z, (int) (k * htOfRow) , (int) (j*(width/rows)) , (int) (k * htOfRow) );
            z=(int)(j*(width/rows));
            }}
        double wdOfRow = width / (cols);
        for (k = 0; k < cols; k++)
            for(j=0; j< cols+1; j++){
            if(j!=3){
            g.drawLine((int) (k*wdOfRow) , z,(int) (k*wdOfRow) , (int) (j*(height/cols)));
            z=(int)(j*(height/cols));}}
        }
}

class Cell{}
```

Comment: The code you have commented out seems to paint the grid in the same way as the first link in your question. I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: @assylias - edited the question and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some logic errors in your drawing loops. I think this should work:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Grid extends Canvas {

    Cell[][] maze;
    int rows;
    int cols;
    int pathSize;
    double width, height;

    public Grid(int rows, int cols, int h, int w) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        maze = new Cell[rows][cols];
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(h, w));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame y = new JFrame();
        y.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Grid f = new Grid(40, 25, 400, 400);
        y.add(f, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        y.setSize(450, 450);
        y.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int k, j, z = 0;
        width = getSize().width;
        height = getSize().height;

        double htOfRow = height / (rows);
        double wdOfRow = width / (cols);

        for (j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
                g.drawLine((int) (k * wdOfRow), (int) (j * htOfRow), (int) (k * wdOfRow), (int) ((j+1) * htOfRow));
            }
        }
        for (j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
                g.drawLine((int) (k * wdOfRow), (int) (j * htOfRow), (int) ((k+1) * wdOfRow), (int) (j * htOfRow));
            }
        }
    }

    class Cell {
    }
}
```

Comment: tried this code with if(k!=3||j!=3) for my new problem and it worked. thank you very much. I see that you changed the arguments I passed to drawLine(). so the starting point is (0,0) then (0,1)? so now I get it.

Comment: your code seems to not work when the grid size is not the same :D

Comment: @Dan Joseph Porcioncula You're right, my `j` and `k` indices were flipped. Edited the answer to fix it.